# Out-of-memory error when building wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets, wxhaskell

I'm currently trying to build wxHaskell as described in the Haskell wiki [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/WxHaskell/Building#On_Windows). Unfortunately I always get the following error message after running the mingw32-make command:

> c:/mingw/bin/.../lib/gcc/mingw2/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   out of memory allocation 31395840
>   bytes
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> mingw32-make: ***
>   [....\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw28u_gcc_custom.dll]
>   Error 1

I know that this is not directly a wxHaskell problem, but it arises only if I use the compiler option "MONOLITHIC=1", which wxHaskell seems to require. So maybe one of the other wxHaskell users knows a solution to this problem.

Since my system specs and the compilers might be of interest, here they are:

- Windows 7
- 4 GB RAM
- Haskell Platform 2011.2.0.1
- MSYS 1.0.11
- Automated MinGW installer from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/)

The strange thing is, that I got it to compile, before I reinstalled windows the other week. Unfortunately I don't know if I was using another MinGW version then or if something else was different.

EDIT: I could solve the problem using [TDM GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer this question: Using TDM GCC solves the problem.